# Headset audio in Microsoft Teams

Tags: sound, dell, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on Dell XPS 15 9570. Headset works fine for most of the apps, but not for Microsoft Teams. I tried both web version (Chrome) and official app. The device just doesn't show up in the Teams audio settings. The same problem happens with Zoom.

Calling someone on Facebook works and I can see the headset available in the audio settings.

How can I make the meetings system work with my headset?

P.S. It is not the headset related issue, cause I tried multiple different ones. And the built-in audio gives a horrible echo and a background noise.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue... looking through this issue: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3015/microphone-for-teams-on-linux-not-working.html I've come up with a strategy, if not a solution yet...

1. Connect headset, set as default audio device, set profile as Headset Unit (HSP/HFP)
2. Open teams meeting
3. Avoid opening device settings

As long as device settings stays closed, it *seems* to continue working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some headphones use force their own codec configuration to be used.

Solution.
Open your sound settings while your bluetooth device is still connected. Go to the configuration settings and change the codec from HSB/HFB to something more universal like SBC or AAC then it will start working.

It probably wasn't working before because microsoft teams don't support LDAC (which is likely to be what your headphones are using, especially if they are high quality headphones.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case currently it is solved by unplugging and replugging the usb-headset while in the Teams call. Previously I did not have to do such magical solution.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

- deactivate in MS Teams - Settings ()Auto-start application and () on close, keep running
- then verify in Linux if your device is ready
- restart MS Teams

> > > Your device is ready to use in Teams.

Comment: How does changing those two settings affect the sound settings?

Comment: On start, Teams reads current system state. If Teams keeps running, it does not notice it. These changes do not particularly _fix_ anything, but may still be helpful.